# How to query all column values, only if query column = null

Tags: mysql, sql, derby

I am using Java Derby DB. When i query, if column condition value is not null then fetch specified data. otherwise null then all data of the column should be fetch.

```
example (EMP_TABLE)
emp_id  emp_name
1       Arun
2       Peter
3       Manoj
```

The query in a function is

```
select * from EMP_TABLE where emp_name = '" + name_param + "'
```

When i pass name_param is 'Peter' then result will be 1

```
When i pass name_param is null then emp_name where clause 
should be omitted. 
(So query is "select * from EMP_TABLE" if emp_name is null)
```

how can do?

Comment: uhm, i don't understand your question-

Comment: what's wrong with just omitting where clause ?

Comment: I cant omit query. because i have it in BIRT engine. It is permanent query with more than 5 where clause. So when i didn't pass parameter, it condition will be null. at the time i want query all values

Answer (score 1):

You can use `like` instead of `=`

```
select * from EMP_TABLE where emp_name **like** '" + name_param + "'
```

If  `name_param` passed as 'Peter' then result will be 1
since the query is

```
select * from EMP_TABLE where emp_name like 'Peter'
```

When `name_param`  is `null` then pass `name_param` as `%`

So The query is `select * from EMP_TABLE where emp_name like '%'`

Hope this will solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing columns in the database with variables used to parameterize the query.  I think you want something like:

```
 select *
 from Emp_Table et
 where ($EmpName is null or $EmpName = emp_name);
```

You can't change how `emp_name is null` works.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution is

```
declare @emp_name varchar(100)
set @emp_name='Peter'
select * from EMP_TABLE where (emp_name = @emp_name or @emp_name is null)
```